# How to access MS SQL Server databases securely without VPN

Tags: sql-server, security

We have an application that must directly access an MS SQL database. The database is in a remote location. Therefore, at the moment, we use a VPN connection which works fine and appears to be safe. However, setting up a VPN connection for each new client is very troublesome. 
Changing the application to use API call or anything similar is not possible.

Is there a way to securely open MS SQL server ports to access the MS SQL DB without using VPN? Or any other suggestion to solve that problem?

Comment: Maybe you should use [SSL encryption in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3299/how-to-configure-ssl-encryption-in-sql-server/)

Comment: This is a duplicate of: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/220081/52344

Comment: Use SSL encryption and setup firewall to only let static IPs of your clients.